# Programmatically Invoke WCF REST Service Without Reference to Contract

Tags: wcf, rest, service, reference, contract

This is useful as a basis:

[How to programmatically connect a client to a WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943148/how-to-programmatically-connect-a-client-to-a-wcf-service)

However, I'd like my client to do the same thing REST-style without knowledge of any service contract.

Seeing how this is done easily in Javascript / jQuery, it seems odd that C# presents no options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# all you need is a standard HttpWebRequest or WebClient like this:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:28330/books");
var response = request.GetResponse();

var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

or

```
var client = new WebClient();
Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("http://localhost:28330/books"));
```

Of course you still need to do something with the XML or JSON (or whatever data format is returned) but that is no different in JavaScript with jQuery.

Comment: Shortly after I posted the question this occurred to me.  Duh.

Answer (score 0):

> Seeing how this is done easily in Javascript / jQuery, it seems odd
>   that C# presents no options.

That is only partially true. It does - you can use `HttpWebRequest` to do a call. Old REST StarterKit (only technology preview) and a new [Web-API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) (only CTP) offers better support in `HttpClient` class.