# WCF exception--Faulted state

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory

I added the WCF service reference to my project. Next step is to create a channel from the code.

```
 WSHttpBinding bindingDialingType = new WSHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress endingPointDialingType = new EndpointAddress("http://wsvc.corporate.my.com/International/DialingService.svc");
        ChannelFactory<IDialingService> iDialingServiceChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IDialingService>(bindingDialingType, endingPointDialingType);
        IDialingService instanceIDialingService = iDialingServiceChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Because I met an exception, so I guess that something wrong with my channel factory code.

```
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
```

To capture the exception, I had the code.

```
My app.config is:

 <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_iLuCRE" />
   </basicHttpBinding>
   <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDialingService">
     <security mode="None" />
   </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
   <endpoint address="http://wsvc.corporate.my.com/LuCRE/LuCRE.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_iLuCRE"
    contract="LuCRE.iLuCRE" name="BasicHttpBinding_iLuCRE" />
   <endpoint address="http://wsvc.corporate.my.com/International/DialingService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDialingService"
    contract="DialingService.IDialingService" name="WSHttpBinding_IDialingService" />
  </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

I used WCFTestClient to test it, however the service does work. I added the service reference to my project and I don't know the code details.

**Updated:**

If I used the code

```
 DialingServiceClient client = new DialingServiceClient();
```

Then call the method through `client`, then everything is fine. Why?

Comment: Is `DialingServiceClient` a generated class from service reference?

Comment: Yes, it is. After I added the service reference. It is inside the `Reference.cs`.

Comment: Then it's highly possible that there is missing element / aspect when consuming the service by creating the binding programmatically, try using `svcutil` to generate the config then compare what is missing `svcutil http://wsvc.corporate.my.com/International/DialingService.svc /config:c:\test.config`

Comment: They are exactly same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binding element security is `None`. You need to also mention it when defining programmatically.

```
WSHttpBinding bindingDialingType = new WSHttpBinding
   { Security = new WSHttpSecurity { Mode = SecurityMode.None } };
```

Comment: It works, one more question. Do I have to close the channel finally?

Comment: yes you should, _[It is recommended that you create your WCF client object first, and then use it and close it inside a single try/catch block.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)_, take a look this [perfect example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943148/how-to-programmatically-connect-a-client-to-a-wcf-service)