# How do I consume a net.tcp service in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core, net.tcp

I'm building an asp.net core 2.1 web application and I need to call an old net.tcp endpoint in order to get details about a booking. The endpoint is configured like so in the web.config of another old application:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="unsecuredLargeTcpBuffer" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="20000000" maxBytesPerRead="20000000" maxStringContentLength="10000000" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>      
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://us-ap-contoso1:12345/Bookings" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="unsecuredLargeTcpBuffer" behaviorConfiguration="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior" contract="Contoso.Contracts.IBookingService" />     
</client>
```

In aspnet core I believe can't use this file based configuration, but need to do it programmatically. I've tried using svcutil to generate a service reference, but this does not work with the net.tcp service.

I've tried to call setup a web.config file with the above configuration and call the endpoint like this

```
public Booking FindBooking(string name, string number)
    {
        var proxy = new BookingSearchServiceProxy();

        try
        {
            var query = new BookingFieldQuery
            {
                BookingNumber = number,
                LastName = name
            };

            Booking booking = proxy.FindSingle(query);

            return booking;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log here
        }
        finally
        {
            proxy.CloseSafely();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But it throws an exception

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Configuration files are not supported.
```

How do I go about this?

I would be grateful for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out to be quite simple. I found this post [How to programmatically connect a client to a wcf service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943206/722510)

Easy.